# Openlayers 3. How to make tootlip for feature

Tags: openlayers-3

Now I'm moving my project from openlayers 2 to openlayers 3. Unfortunately I can't find how to show title (tooltip) for feature. In OL2 there was a style named `graphicTitle`.
Could you give me advice how to implement tooltip on OL3?

Comment: Have you tried google? Google it for "ol3 tooltip", there's a lot links

Comment: Tried, but got no result. Almost all links are moving to OL2

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/Lg0eurr5/) if it's what you'd like.

Comment: You should check this link [OpenLayers 3.10.1 - Feature Popup](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166613/openlayers-3-10-1-feature-popup)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is example from ol3 developers.
[jsfiddle.net/uarf1888/](http://jsfiddle.net/uarf1888/)

```
var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: tooltip,
  offset: [10, 0],
  positioning: 'bottom-left'
});
map.addOverlay(overlay);

function displayTooltip(evt) {
  var pixel = evt.pixel;
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
    return feature;
  });
  tooltip.style.display = feature ? '' : 'none';
  if (feature) {
    overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
    tooltip.innerHTML = feature.get('name');
  }
};

map.on('pointermove', displayTooltip);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic example using the `ol` library. The most important is to define the `overlay` object. We will need an element to append the text we want to display in the tooltip, a position to show the tooltip and the offset (x and y) where the tooltip will start.

```js
const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip')
const overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: tooltip,
  offset: [10, 0],
  positioning: 'bottom-left'
})
map.addOverlay(overlay)
```

Now, we need to dynamically update the `innerHTML` of the tooltip.

```js
const displayTooltip = evt => {
    const pixel = evt.pixel;
    const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, f => f)
    tooltip.style.display = feature ? '' : 'none'
    if (feature) {
    overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate)
    tooltip.innerHTML = feature.get('name')
    }
}

map.on('pointermove', displayTooltip)
```

```js
let styleCache = {}
const styleFunction = (feature, resolution) => {
  // 2012_Earthquakes_Mag5.kml stores the magnitude of each earthquake in a
  // standards-violating <magnitude> tag in each Placemark.  We extract it from
  // the Placemark's name instead.
  const name = feature.get('name')
  const magnitude = parseFloat(name.substr(2))
  const radius = 5 + 20 * (magnitude - 5)
  
  let style = styleCache[radius]
  if (!style) {
    style = [new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: radius,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.4)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.2)',
          width: 1
        })
      })
    })]
    styleCache[radius] = style
  }
  
  return style
}

const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/5f4202f2d49d8574fd3c/raw/2c7ee40e3f4ad9dd4c8d9fb31ec53aa07e3865a9/earthquakes.kml',
    format: new ol.format.KML({
      extractStyles: false
    })
  }),
  style: styleFunction
})

const raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.Stamen({
    layer: 'toner'
  })
})

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
})

const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip')
const overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: tooltip,
  offset: [10, 0],
  positioning: 'bottom-left'
})
map.addOverlay(overlay)

const displayTooltip = evt => {
  const pixel = evt.pixel;
  const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, f => f)
  tooltip.style.display = feature ? '' : 'none'
  if (feature) {
    overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate)
    tooltip.innerHTML = feature.get('name')
  }
}

map.on('pointermove', displayTooltip)
```

```css
#map {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 10pt sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map">
  <div id="tooltip" class="tooltip"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.4.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.4.0/ol.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [Icon Symobolizer](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/icon.html?q=overlay) example from the openlayers website. It shows how to have a popup when you click on an icon feature. The same principle applies to any kind of feature. This is what I used as an example when I did mine.

Comment: This example shows how to customize the buttons tooltips with Bootstrap.
I need example how to show tooltip for feature.

Comment: There you go. I edited the link to a relevant example. I was able to use the as an example for doing popups on polygon geometry features.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to make simple title as it was in OL2. Any html element can have this attribute....
If I can't to do so I'll try you example.

Comment: Features are not rendered as html or svg elements in OpenLayers 3. Everything is rendered to a canvas element. For simple tooltips, you may want to have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uarf1888/.