# Need a map for Angular with html info window function and no personal account key

Tags: angular, google-maps, maps, openstreetmap

I need a map for Angular 6 where I can show info windows for my markers containing HTML. beside that I need to style the map (having a dark and a light theme). The last thing is that it must not be using a personal account key like Google Maps. It doesn't matter if I have to buy the map component :-)

Can you suggest something?

Thanks very much in advance :-)

Comment: https://openlayers.org/

Comment: @YoukouleleY Thanks very much for your reply :-) Is there a good angular library for integrating openlayers into angular and TypeScript?

Comment: Openlayers has TypeScript definitions, then integrates easily into any Angular app. I don't think you should look at an Angular library since it would bind your project to a library that may have limitations and may not be maintained in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot, please make an answer so I can mark it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Google Maps, then use [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/). It integrates well to Angular apps thanks to TypeScript definitions and covers what you want to do.

An example of marker with HTML can be found here: [Openlayers 3. How to make tootlip for feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848697/openlayers-3-how-to-make-tootlip-for-feature).

I don't know much about the theming part but it looks like it's possible: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/color-manipulation.html

Comment: I has just started coding Angular 5 and TypeScript, and I think it is confusing that I can't find any examples for OpenLayers using TypeScript. Am I am having problems understanding how to convert the Java script to Type Script. The example you link to is also JS and OpenLayers 3 :-|